# How to pass value in key value pair jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass(return) **data-filter** value and **children text** , I am able to pass the **data-filter** value but I am unable to pass the children text. My HTML and JQuery as following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar-filter').on('click', function() {
    var filterobj = {};
    $(".sidebar-filter").each(function(index, ele) {

      var filterval = $(this).children('a').text();
      var filterkey = $(this).data('filter');

      filterobj[filterkey] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li[data-filter=' + filterkey + '].active')).map(function(el) {
        return ele.value;
      });

    });
    console.log(filterobj);

  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="sidebar-filter " data-filter="category" data-value="1">
    <a href="#">Item Name</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My return will be like:

category: Array [ **undefined** ]

I want value inside the array instead of undefined.

Comment: 1) you don't have any `li` with class active  2) `.map(function(el) { ele.value...` will use the `ele` from the outer .each.  Fix those and it works(?) https://jsfiddle.net/rf76teyb/  but 3) `li` elements don't have a `.value` property, so it's unclear what you're *trying* to get in the final array.  Maybe `$(el).data("value")`?  https://jsfiddle.net/rf76teyb/1/

Comment: I have css to add class=active on click. For now data-filter value is printed but I am unable to pass text inside a to array. I want to pass either data-vale from li or text from a tag.

Comment: It works. Thank you. 
Can you please share how can I pass children('a').text(); same as $(el).data("value")

Comment: `$(el).text()` will get the text from all the children, no need to select children first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer, might be of help to someone others too

```
    filterobj[filterkey]= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll
          ('li[data-filter=' + filterkey+'].active')).map(function(el){
            return $(el).data("value")
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `li`s don't have attribute `value`, actually you want to read attribute `data-value`, you can achieve your goal by converting  `return ele.value;` to `return el.getAttribute('data-value');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar-filter').on('click', function() {
    var filterobj = {};
    $(".sidebar-filter").each(function(index, ele) {

      var filterval = $(this).children('a').text();
      var filterkey = $(this).data('filter');

      filterobj[filterkey] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li[data-filter=' + filterkey + '].active')).map(function(el) {
        return el.getAttribute("data-value");
      });

    });
    console.log(filterobj);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="sidebar-filter active" data-filter="category" data-value="1">
    <a href="#">Item Name</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This way its throwing null: 

category: Array [ null ]

Comment: are you sure you have li with `active` class?

Comment: take a look at the snippet in my response, I manually added `active` class to `li`. is the result what you expected?

Comment: Yes, I have the same where active class will be added with on(click) event from another js file. But with your code its passing null only, not a value.

Comment: there was a mistake in the code, it should be `return el.getAttribute('data-value')`. it doesn't work again?